# How to implement server messages with Websockets in Codeigniter on AWS? A

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, websocket, amazon-lightsail

So I just got Websockets working in my Codeigniter app with this library. It works just fine on localhost, but when I push all this code to my AWS instance, I can't get any messages.

I already did all the steps in the readme to add the library to my server, and I am even able to do the test with sending messages between two 'clients'. However, I need to send messages from my controller and I need them to be displayed by my view.

My controller class:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use WebSocket\Client;

public function sendMessage() {
    // Create client object
    $this->client = new Client('ws://0.0.0.0:8282');
    //send null message for verification
    $this->client->send(json_encode(array('user_id' => 1, 'message' => null)));
    //send actual message
    $this->client->send(json_encode(array('user_id' => 1, 'message' => 'Super cool message to myself!')));
}
```

The socket code in my view is:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8282');
var client = {
    user_id: 1,
    recipient_id: null,
    type: 'socket',
    token: null,
    message: null
};

conn.onopen = function (e) {
    conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));
    $('#messages').append('<font color="green">Successfully connected as user ' + client.user_id + '</font><br>');
};

conn.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data.message) {
        $('#messages').append(data.user_id + ' : ' + data.message + '<br>');
    }
    if (data.type === 'token') {
        $('#token').html('JWT Token : ' + data.token);
    }
};
```

Again, this works on localhost, but I never see my 'Super cool message to myself' in my AWS. Why is this? Is it because I'm listening on ws://localhost:8282 in my socket code in the view? I already tried to change localhost to my server's ip address, but my view can never login as a user.